# How does composition vs aggregation differ in code?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have been reading about composition and aggregation. I think I understand the basic of the two different relationship types. However how it actually looks in code is still unclear.

If you have a compound object, does that mean you never write `new OtherObject()` outside of the compound object that is being defined? You never pass a reference of type `OtherObject` to the compound object, it is maintained internally?

Is it right that all cases where you do pass a reference you are not longer dealing with a composition but aggregation? Where does the line between the two go? I don't understand the rules for when you are allowed to talk about objects that are part of a composition and not.

Answer (score 4):

> Composition is a **strong** association.
>
> Aggregation is a **weak** association.

***Aggregation** is a special case of association. A directional association between objects. When an object ‘has-a’ another object, then you have got an aggregation between them. Direction between them specified which object contains the other object.*

***Composition** is a special case of aggregation. In a more specific manner, a restricted aggregation is called composition. When an object contains the other object, **if the contained object cannot exist without the existence of container object**, then it is called composition.*

Composition is an Association where the containing object `b` is responsible for the lifetime of the contained object `a`. If you pass the reference of an already created object `a` to another object `b` , then `b` is not able to control the life cycle of `a` .That means `a` can exist even without `b`.

```
class A {
   B b ;
   A(B b ) { this.b = b; }
 }
```

Here the existence of `b` doesn't depend on `a`, but `A` does contain objects of `B`.**Aggregation**.

```
class A {
 B b ;
 A() { b = new B();}
}
```

Here `b` depends on the existence of object of `A` . If there are no objects of `A` , there are no objects of `B` either. **Composition.**

Comment: So if `Keyboard` is a composite class and you also have `Button` class that is part of the `Keyboard` you are not allowed to say `new Button()` etc outside of the Keyboard class? If you need to add a new button is it allowed to define a method that accepts a String for example `addButton(final String keyText)`? But a method `addButton(final Button button)` is not allowed? If it were an aggregate the last example would have been allowed?

Comment: Let say you have a Book class and a Feedback class. Each book have a list with feedback. When I delete a book I want all feedback for that book to be deleted as well since it doesn't make sense to have feedback on non-existing books. This sounds like the relationship is of type composition doesn't it? Or is it not? However, if the each feedback have many properties such as name, date, description, categories and further nested objects don't you get very long methods on book `addFeedback(final String name, final String description, final Date createdDate ....);`? I am confused about this!

Comment: @LuckyLuke Yes, you understood correct regarding composition of books and feedbacks

Comment: @PrasadKharkar But that doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @LuckyLuke, I edited my answer accordingly. Please check whether it answers your question.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot ...And should the objects that are contained in a composition always be defined in the classes where they are used? I mean, how do you ensure that it is not referenced outside?

Answer (score 0):

consider following

This is example of **composition**. **B  is associated with A such that it cannot exist without A**

```
      Class A{
         B b = new B();
       }
```

If you create object of class `A` then B will also be created and if A is destroyed, then B also be destroyed.

consider example of **Aggregation**. **B is associated with A but can exist wihtout A**

```
      Class A{
         C c = new C();
         B b = c.someMethodThatReturnsExistingBObject();
      }

      class C{
         B b = new B();
         public B someMethodThatReturnsExistingBObject(){
             return b;
         }
       }
```

then this will return an object that has external reference. i.e. it still lives outside this class. So even if A object is destroyed, B object will live outside also .

**Is it right that all cases where you do pass a reference you are not longer dealing with a composition but aggregation?**

Yes, because the meaning of composition is that there is not any external existence of the object. As soon as you are passing a reference,it will be considered as `aggregation` because when passing a reference , you are passing an external object to it which will have existence from outside because it was passed from outside.